# Cant identify blank string value

Tags: java, html, jsoup

Hey I got a problem in my app currently im parsing values from an website whit Jsoup and then parsing them to floats but the problem is that some of those values are something like this : " " and I can't identify those ! And I got a bug saying can't pass those values to float ! How can I make that when I got that value from website I pass it to a string whit the value "N/A" or something ? I have tried something like this :

```
   if(valueFromwebsite.equals(" ")){
valueFromwebsite = "N/A"
}
```

But its not working !

This is the website : http://www.dges.gov.pt/guias/detcursopi.asp?codc=9186&code=3043

And the value that im parsing is the last ".tvag" that in this case is " " but normally would be "115,5"

Comment: try removing the space between the 2 `"`

Comment: `if (valueFromwebsite.trim().isEmpty()) {`

Comment: Ok i will try each of your suggestions and give feedback later thanks !

Comment: None of your suggestions worked :(

Comment: @Jennifer then your `String` is not empty, print it, char by char to see the real content. I don't know if `trim` remove `\t` for example